# Как проанализировать, где в коде случаются задержки

Tags: php

Учусь разрабатывать на PHP какое-то время и в качестве поприща пытаюсь написать что-то подобное системе поиска авиабилетов. Пока что в системе всего пару функций, несколько обработчиков JSON-строк и несколько cURL-запросов к API. Не более 1000 строк кода. Но страница со скриптом загружается 2-3 секунды, что на данном этапе уже недопустимо. Работая с jQuery на клиенте, можно запустить вкладку Network и понять, где случается задержка. А можно ли сделать так же на PHP?

Comment: гугляндекс -> `"php profiler|профайлер"` (и 80% за то, что задержки будут на стороне curl)

Comment: `xhprof` в помощь

Comment: @PinkTux я вручную определил причину медленного исполнения кода. Это рекурсивный поиск в многомерном массиве(который получился из 2,3мб json-данных).

Answer (score 1):

Как сказал @pink-tux, задержки на стороне CURL, в частности, из-за того, что запросы выполняются последовательно, что занимает много времени.
Как вариант, можно использовать загрузку пустой страницы, а потом, уже с загруженной страницы, используя AJAX (`$.when()` и `$.get()` у jQuery, например), обращаться к API (придется написать самому), который будет возвращать данные, полученные от CURL, и выводить их на страницу. Места, в которые будут вставляться данные, можно временно, до самой загрузки, заменить спиннером.